# Unable to add programmatically a view

Tags: android, android-layout, view

i have the sequent issue. I have a ScrollView like:

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearInsideScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/row1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            layout="@layout/catalog_row" />

        <include layout="@layout/horizontal_row" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/row2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            layout="@layout/catalog_row" />

        <include layout="@layout/horizontal_row" />

        ....
```

and horizontal row is like

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="20dip" >

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

(a transparent space separate each "catalog_row" view)

Now programmatically i need to replicate this layout, so add a new "catalog_row" and "horizontal_row".

In my code i do something like:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view
            .findViewById(R.id.linearInsideScroll);
View firstRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.catalog_row, null, false);
...
linearLayout.addView(firstRow);
linearLayout.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.horizontal_row,
                null, false));
```

but something strange happen. Only firstRow view is added to layout, but not horizontal_row.
what's wrong?

Comment: I dont understand one thing over here why are you adding this `layout horizontal_row` again? this layout you already `<include>` in your main layout.

Comment: because when an event occour, a add new firstRow view (under horizontal_row declared inside xml) then add another horizontal_row below firstRow. ScrollView it's like: "catalog_row"-"horizontal_row"-"catalog_row"-"horizontal_row"-"catalog_row"-"horizontal_row"-...

Comment: all right. then inflate one by one layout and add into your scrollview. and remove static <include> from main layout.